# How to filter dynamic created tableview, based on user selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I want to filter a tableview based on a String value set by the user.
The tableview is generated with a Cell consisting of several components (Images, labels, etc.) all which is located in a "mess" of Arrays, and Dictionaries. I am using below code. When I filter i just hide the cells, but they are still taking up space in the tableview. 
What is the best way to apply the filter and thereby only get the cells which comply?
The field which I'm filtering on is the topic.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if filterChoice == "Alle"
    {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsCell") as News_TableViewCell
        cell.subject!.text = subjects[indexPath.row]
        if videoEmbedCode.valueForKey(self.recordIDs[indexPath.row]) != nil
        {
            var iframeCode: NSString = videoEmbedCode.valueForKey(self.recordIDs[indexPath.row]) as String
            var html = "<html><body>\(iframeCode)</body></html>"
            cell.webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL :nil)
            cell.webView.hidden = false
        } else if self.imageCache.valueForKey(self.recordIDs[indexPath.row]) != nil
        {
            cell.newsImage.image = self.imageCache.valueForKey(self.recordIDs[indexPath.row]) as? UIImage
            cell.newsImage.hidden = false
        } else
        {
        }
        if topics.valueForKey(self.recordIDs[indexPath.row]) != nil
        {
            cell.topicLabel.text = topics.valueForKey(self.recordIDs[indexPath.row]) as? String
        }
        else
        {
            cell.topicLabel.text = ""
        }
        return cell
    }
    else if topics.valueForKey(self.recordIDs[indexPath.row]) as? String == filterChoice
    {
        //Only return cells with specified topic
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsCell") as News_TableViewCell
        if topics.valueForKey(self.recordIDs[indexPath.row]) != nil
        {
            cell.topicLabel.text = topics.valueForKey(self.recordIDs[indexPath.row]) as? String
        }
        else
        {
            cell.topicLabel.text = ""
        }

        cell.subject!.text = subjects[indexPath.row]

        if videoEmbedCode.valueForKey(self.recordIDs[indexPath.row]) != nil
        {
            var iframeCode: NSString = videoEmbedCode.valueForKey(self.recordIDs[indexPath.row]) as String
            var html = "<html><body>\(iframeCode)</body></html>"
            cell.webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL :nil)
            cell.webView.hidden = false
        } else if self.imageCache.valueForKey(self.recordIDs[indexPath.row]) != nil
        {
            cell.newsImage.image = self.imageCache.valueForKey(self.recordIDs[indexPath.row]) as? UIImage
            cell.newsImage.hidden = false
        } else
        {
        }
        return cell
    }
    else
    {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.hidden = true
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track number of cells in DataSource method, that asks you about number of cells for current section.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Here
}
```

If you just do `cell.hidden = true` space won't disappear, it will just hide content. It's because all cells layout calculated in other methods.

If you want to hide space for such cells you could choose several solution:

1. (Best) calculate number of non hidden cells, return new count in `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` and recalculate dictionary with info for `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`
2. It not good solution, but for your problem can take place. In method, that asked for tableView cells height `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat` just return 0 for hidden cells.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate a bit? Tnx.

Comment: Maybe I little bit confused, you need to filter table view cells, but gets empy speces?

Comment: The code work fine. Problem is returning an Empty cell isn't a good solution. Because it still takes up space in the tableview.
I imagine something about storing the Topics in another array and then match with filter-string.

Comment: Inspired me to this solution:
Save all cells with their topic in an array.
Saved index.path in a var.
If topic was selected, Iterate over new array with index.path as index. In that way the new array held the position of the specific cells in the old array.

Hmm. Doesn't make much sense.
But anyway, I solved it. Thanks for your input ;-)